# Posting a link to a fan page through an application

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a custom made CMS that the users have the option of posting to the company's 'fan page' when they post a message. This code uses the FacebookAPI code provided by Facebook to use the Graph API in a C# application (actually a WCF webservice).

We have had various problems posting before (see [this bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10005) and [this discussion](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=323368#p323368)). This had been working for a while, but now returns a 400/Bad Request.

I have tried two different (known working before) api tokens. No code has changed in months on this setup.

I'm wondering how I can figure out why it now will no longer post. Has something changed with the tokens its requesting?

This is the code I am using:

```
FacebookAPI api = new FacebookAPI(token);

Dictionary<string, string> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

postArgs["link"] = url;
postArgs["message"] = message;

try
{
    JSONObject jsonresult = api.Post("me/links", postArgs);
    result = "ok";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    result = "Post Failed - " + e.Message.ToString();
}
```

My exception is stating a 400/Bad Request

**update:** I also noticed that according to the [Authentication Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), some of the tokens now have an expiration, which mine doesn't seem to have. Could this be an issue? For example, my token is a ~100 char string, with 4 sections seperated by 3 pipes (|). Their examples then have an extra &expires_in=64090.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because this is essentially a tech support question for facebook?

Comment: I am confused myself - mainly be cause Facebook now wants people posting to stackoverflow! https://developers.facebook.com/support/

Comment: I will be adding a bug report to their site as well for this, but also felt it was a legitimate 'technical question' for their system.

Comment: Confused about the votes to close - I feel like I am asking a valid question - how to post through the API to a page versus a profile.?

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to post links, or statuses now you need a user access_token and permission to links.  Be sure the user has given the application doing the link-post has publish_stream perms.  Also the message parameter should be ignored on post but i would not pre-fill it just to avoid errors.

> You can post a link on the user's behalf by issuing an HTTP POST
>   request to PROFILE_ID/feed with the publish_stream permissions and the
>   following parameters.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links

javascript sample i use to make posts.

```
window.feedthis = function(shf,point,clk) {
     ptsT=point-shf+clk;
             FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
           // message: 'Testing Feed',
            caption: 'I survived '+shf+' Levels in Another Grid. I earned '+point+' points with '+clk+' clicks.',
            name: 'Another Grid',
            link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/anothergrid/?ref=link',
            //to: '391793380398',
            description: 'Another Grid, A color elemination Puzzle game by Shawn E Carter.',
            picture: 'https://shawnsspace.com/ShawnsSpace.toon.nocolor..png',
            properties: [{ text: 'Play the Game', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/anothergrid/?ref=achievement'}
                            //{ text: 'ShawnsSpace', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/shawnsspace/?ref=anothergrid'}
                            ],
            actions: [
            { name: 'Another Grid', link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/anothergrid/'}
            ]       
            });
            };
```

Comment: Can you do this as a page versus a user?